# Using Stripe API, I need to see a transfer to my bank and all the Stripe payments that make it up

Tags: stripe-payments

When Stripe sends a transfer to my bank account, it is often a cluster of customer payments. Example: A $100 transfer to my bank account is four different customers paying $25 each. Since they paid on the same day, Stipe sent it as one transfer of $100.

Via the API, I know how to see the transfers to my bank account, but I only see the total amount, and not the breakdown of which customer payments made of the total amount.

TIA,
Dave

Answer (score 2):

If you’re using an automatic payout, you can see the charges included in the Payout by retrieving the [List All Balance Transactions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/list) and [expanding](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) the [source](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/object#balance_transaction_object-source) of the property. This will give you the transfer/ charge ids you’re looking for on the payout. Also, under the charge object, you’ll also see the payment intent id under `payment_intent`. They document this [here](https://stripe.com/docs/expand/use-cases#charges-in-payout) and show an example code on how to achieve what you’re looking for. However, if you're using a manual payout, you'd need to track this on your end.

Comment: Thank you, @pgs! After hours of poking around and 30 minutes with Stripe tech support, your info is just what I needed.  

I did use this to make the final API call. below. Note the "po_ABCDEFG" needs to be the payout ID code gleaned from a call like `https://api.stripe.com/v1/payouts`   


API call that gave me the details on the payout:
`https://api.stripe.com/v1/balance_transactions?payout=po_ABCDEFG&type=charge&expand[]=data.source`.